# How can I render the query inside this function?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to render values to a table with a delete link. Now my problem is that I need to pass the mysql row id to a function that will delete the value from the table and refresh. Everything is ok except for the delex sub-query, 
I have failed to get the id inside the function, it just passed null values to the function
how do I get the row id inside the function

```
 deletex($RowID)
```

my query is here. any ideas?,

```
$query="SELECT username as '{$mylanguage['username']}',
            vchCode as '{$mylanguage['voucher_code']}',
            vchStatus as '{$mylanguage['status']}',
            vchDateCreated as '{$mylanguage['date']}',
            vchDateUsed as '{$mylanguage['date_used']}',  
            CONCAT('<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"return deletx(\'',SELECT vchID,'\')\">".$mylanguage['delete']."</a>') as '&nbsp;' 
        FROM $tablename 
        LEFT JOIN #__users ON $uniqueKey = id
        ".$_SESSION['query_condition']." 
        ORDER BY vchID DESC 
        LIMIT ". ($pagination['start'] - 1) .",{$pagination['size']}";
```

Comment: `how do I get the row id inside the function`, but which function??

Comment: Is `deletex()` a JavaScript function?

Comment: HERE IS THE FUNCTION AND YES ITS JAVA SCRIPT.  `function deletx(i){
 if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this voucher?')){
  $x("#specialAction").val("vchDelete");
  $x("#specialId").val(i);
  $x("#specialForm").submit();
 }
 return false;
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think returning HTML from a SQL query is a particulary good idea. You should rather return the ID, then insert it into the HTML using PHP.

Add `vchID` to the select. Lets assume you got your SQL result as an assosiative array named `result`, the code would look like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return deletex(<?= $result|'vchID'] ?>)">
    <?= $mylanguage['delete'] ?>
</a>
```

Comment: OK did not work smooth but pushed me in the right direction, I first performed a query for Ids,  inserted each column into an array, as such was able to derive the delete Array based on Id array, then looped the arrays values, into a table. whoops lots of code, but it worked. thanks. only I had to slow down my script just to alow for one delete. multiple deletes meant loops through a new array,im not a fan of multilevel looping.